# JTable cambiar tipo de objeto fila java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Buenas, tengo un problema si quiero por ejemplo que cada columna de un jtable pueda almacenar un tipo de objeto diferente por ejemplo en la primera columna un string y en la segunda un double,

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

No comprendo la pregunta, el DefaultTableModel que puedes utilizar para construir tu tabla con los valores que quiereas. Por ejemplo

```
    Object data[][] = {{"Hola", new Double(1.1)}, {"Otra fila", new Double(2.2)}};
    Object[] colsNames = {"String", "Double"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, colsNames);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)